# How to pause/resume individual Spring JMS message listeners

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

My Spring Boot JMS application is consuming messages from several SQS queues. Each queue needs to connect to a different external resource in order to process its messages. If there's an external resource failure I expect the consumer requiring that resource will rapidly drain the queue to a DLQ and that's no fun.

I need to be able to suspend (pause) the message listener for each consumer independently when my code detects that its resource is offline (e.g. comms exception calling REST endpoint).

How can I do this?

After searching for platform support for this, I found the AbstractJmsListeningContainer which (via the Lifecycle interface) supports stop() and start() methodsm though it doesn't document whether start can be invoked following a stop call.

My concern is that there appears to be one shared instance among my multiple @JmsListener annotated consumers; so stopping one queue stops them all and I don't want that.

How can I achieve my end goal of pausing individual consumers?

I have seen references to using multiple bean definitions like so:

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container1(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
// snip
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container2(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
// snip
}
```

...but never seen any explanation stating how and when one will be used versus the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046837/how-to-pause-and-start-consuming-message-using-jmslistener).

Yes, you can call `start()` after `stop()`.

Note that `stop()` only stops the threads; the connection remains open.

If you want to shut everything down, call `shutDown()` after `stop()` and then `initialize()` before `start()`.

You should not call `stop()` on a listener thread, though - hand it off to another thread and wait until `isRunning()` is false.

Comment: Is there one instance of SimpleMessageListenerContainer per each component listening, or is it shared among all components listening for messages? If it's the latter, then I still don't have an answer.

Comment: As I said in the answer I pointed you to. Each listener gets a container registered by its id.

Comment: After experimenting with my runtime environment I observed this first hand. 

Assigning a distinct id to each listener, I was able to then obtain the MessageListenerContainer from an autowired instance of JmsListenerEndpointRegistry via getListenerContainer(container-id).

Each instance is unique and stopping one instance halts the inbound messages only for that container.

Thanks!