# Right way to stop the queue listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

saw here a way to stop the listener with the method stop in DefaultMessageListenerContainer [How to pause/resume individual Spring JMS message listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836140/how-to-pause-resume-individual-spring-jms-message-listeners), but I don't know if it's the right way considering my requirement. if I'm processing a message while stop is called, it will continue the processing? or will drop the message? can stop() fail?

Comment: use the shutDown() that allows for completion of processing message, before shutting down.

Comment: IMO: Stop method call will stop delivery of any new messages, however the processing of current message will continue.