# Enable and disable SQS listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, listener, amazon-sqs

I am working on spring boot project that uses docker and k8s for deployment. I have created a SQS listener class that listens to a SQS queue. I have a requirement where I need to implement a functionality that enables and disables the listener. Does sqs listner provide any such functionality?  How can I implement this feature? Below are the libraries that I am using to implement SQS listner `

```
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.4.2'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.4.2'
```

I saw this answer - [How can I Stop/start/Pause a @JmsListener (the clean way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588352/how-can-i-stop-start-pause-a-jmslistener-the-clean-way), jms has a way to register and de-register the listner. Does SQS listner also provide something like this?